Filter columns from a list and create new column if not present in list
I have a dataframe df with 300+ columns.
I have a list columns that have 112 column names. However, there can be situation where few column names from columns may not be present in df.columns.
If so, how to filter df with columns that are present in columns and for the one there are not present, create a new column in dfwith values 0?

You could find the set difference between columns and df.columns and use that to create new columns with values of 0:
df[list(set(columns).difference(df.columns))] = 0

For example:
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : range(5), 'B' : range(5,0,-1) })
#    A  B
# 0  0  5
# 1  1  4
# 2  2  3
# 3  3  2
# 4  4  1

columns = ['E', 'A', 'C']
df[list(set(columns).difference(df.columns))] = 0

Output:
   A  B  E  C
0  0  5  0  0
1  1  4  0  0
2  2  3  0  0
3  3  2  0  0
4  4  1  0  0

You can then index using columns:
df[columns]

Output:
   E  A  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  2  0
3  0  3  0
4  0  4  0


@d_b Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?
